# Where is the my.cnf located on a Vista?

Tags: mysql, windows-vista, my.cnf

Would anyone know where I could find the my.cnf file(s) on Vista? I am using XAMPP (C:/xampp) and I tried searching within that directory, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: usually in C:/xampp/mysql/my.cnf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my.cnf or my.ini is probably in C:\xampp\mysql\

If not there, you can try the following, which I found [here](http://www.a3webtech.com/index.php/xampp-3.html):

To find these MySQL config files, do this:

1. Go to Folder Options: in any folder, go to the top horizontal main text menu >> Tools >> Folder Options
2. Enable 'View Hidden Files and Folders', and 'View Protected System Files', save & exit
3. Go to C Drive, locate and rename the my.ini file, which will now be visible. Rename it as my.ini.bak
4. Go to /xampp/msql/bin - locate and rename my.cnf, to my.cnf.bak
5. If there is no file my.cnf, but there is one called my - then that is the one you want. Rename it to my.cnf.bak